# How to catch any err msg in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In the [official docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-Error), I see this:

```
Meteor.call("methodName", function (error) {
  // identify the error
  if (error.error === "logged-out") {
    // show a nice error message
    Session.set("errorMessage", "Please log in to post a comment.");
  }
});
```

I want to catch an exception in a method regardless of what the err msg is. Is this the way to do that:

```
Meteor.call('insertJobLocationData', companyid, jobloc, function (err) {
if (err) {
  Session.set("lastErrMsg", "insertJobLocationData failed");
}
```

?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you've put in the second code block.  Should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Generically you'll probably want to handle results as well. Ex:

```
Meteor.call('myFunction',parameter1,parameter2,function(err,result){
  if (err) {
    console.log("Whoopsies! "+err.error);
    Session.set("lastErrMsg", "insertJobLocationData failed");
  } else console.log("Result is "+result);
});
```

As your app gets closer to deploying you're going to want to look at [Kadira](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/kadira) which is great not only for performance monitoring but also for error monitoring.

Comment: `err` is an object, so won't `+`-ing it to a string just give you "[object Object]"?

Comment: Depends on what generated it right? Most Meteor errors seem to come back as simple strings. If he throws an error with `new Meteor.error` then yes it will be an object; the logic will work but the console.log() won't be that informative.

Comment: But you're right for an error coming back from `Meteor.call` -changed answer.